# How to use auto with repeat in custom tactics?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

In my coq development I am learning how to create new tactics tailored to my problem domain, a la [Prof. Adam Chlipala](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Match.html).

On that page he describes how to create powerful tactics by wrapping `repeat` around a `match` that responds to various interesting conditions.  The `repeat` then iterates, allowing for far-reaching inference.

The use of `repeat` has a caveat (emphasis mine):

> The `repeat` that we use here is called a *tactical*, or tactic combinator. The behavior of `repeat t` is to loop through running `t`, running `t` on all generated subgoals, running `t` on *their* generated subgoals, and so on. When `t` fails at any point in this search tree, that particular subgoal is left to be handled by later tactics. **Thus, it is important never to use `repeat` with a tactic that always succeeds.**

Now, I already have a powerful tactic in use, [`auto`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#sec390).  It similarly strings together chains of steps, this time found from hint databases.  From `auto`'s page:

> `auto` either solves completely the goal or else leaves it intact. **`auto` and `trivial` never fail.**

Boo! I have already invested some effort in curating `auto`'s hint databases, but it seems I am forbidden from employing them in tactics using `repeat` (that is, interesting tactics.)

Is there some variation of `auto` that can fail, or otherwise be used correctly in loops?

For example, perhaps this variant fails when it "leaves [the goal] intact".

**EDIT**: Incorporating `auto` into loops isn't the "right" way to do it anyway (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41171406/580412)), but the actual question of a failing version of auto is still perhaps interesting.

Comment: It seems to me that your question is actually two questions: the one in the title [`progress auto` could be the thing you are (were) looking for]; and the one you describe in the body, to which you've already given an answer.

Comment: True, I suppose I should rename it "How to use auto with repeat in custom tactics?"

Comment: The new title sounds good, but won't it (partially) invalidate @Zimm i48's answer? It would be great if you could actually split the questions, because both of them are interesting. But it's your call :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @AntonTrunov you can always use the [`progress`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.progress) tactical to make the tactic fail if the goal has not been changed. In the case of [`auto`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.auto) since it is supposed to solve the goal or leave it unchanged, you can also wrap it in `solve [ auto ]` which will have the same effect because it will fail if `auto` does not solve the goal completely ([here is the doc for `solve`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.solve)).