# How to leverage auto's searching and hint databases in custom tactics?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

In my coq development I am learning how to create new tactics tailored to my problem domain, a la [Prof. Adam Chlipala](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Match.html).  On that page he describes how to create powerful custom tactics by e.g. combining `repeat` with `match`.

Now, I already have a powerful one-shot tactic in use, [`auto`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#sec390).  It strings together chains of steps found from hint databases.  I have invested some effort in curating those hint databases, so I'd like to continue using it as well.

However this presents a problem.  **It isn't clear what the "right" way is to incorporate `auto`'s functionality into customized tactics.**

For example, since (per its page) `auto` always either solves the goal or does nothing, putting it inside a loop is no more powerful than calling it once after the loop.

To see why this isn't ideal, consider a hypothetical way to directly call a single "step" of `auto`, which succeeds if it could make a change (as opposed to only when it solved the goal) and fails otherwise.  Such single-steps could be interleaved with custom behavior in a match repeat loop, allowing us to e.g. `try contradiction` or `try congruence` at intermediate points within the search tree.

Are there good design patterns for incorporating `auto`'s functionality into custom tactics?

Can `auto`'s behavior be decomposed into "single step" tactics that we can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do instead would be to incorporate other tactics within [`auto`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.auto).
You can do so by using the [`Hint Extern num pat => mytactic : mybase`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:cmdv.hint-extern) command where `num` is a priority number (0 being the highest priority), `pat` a pattern to filter when the hint should be used and `mytactic` and `mybase` are of course the tactic you want to apply and the base you want to add the hint to (do not use the default `core`; build up your custom base instead and call it with `auto with mybase`; if you do not want to include the lemmas from the `core` base in the search, add the fake base `nocore`: `auto with mybase nocore`).

If you start relying on `auto` very much, I would switch instead to the almost equivalent but better behaved [`typeclasses eauto with mybase`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/type-classes.html#coq:tacn.typeclasses-eauto). Contrary to what its name suggests, it is a general purpose tactic that has nothing to do with type classes (as long as you explicitly provide the hint base on which it should be working). One of the main behavior difference to know is that the search depth is unbounded by default. So beware of possible infinite loops or fix a finite limit with the variant `typeclasses eauto num with mybase`.

Comment: How would this allow us to combine auto-like searching with, say, `congruence` or other solvers for restricted fragments?

Comment: @phs: What I'm suggesting is calling congruence and such *from* the auto tactic.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Do you know of a variant of `typeclasses eauto` similar to `auto using ...`, where explicit terms can be added to the search?  If it's in the manual, it's not somewhere I could see.

Comment: No unfortunately this syntax is not available yet for typeclasses eauto although you can get the same result using singleton hint bases that you add to the with clause (`typeclasses eauto with mybase mysingletonbase`).

Comment: Fair enough.  I might try scripting up automatic creation/population/use/disposal of hint dbs for that purpose.  Perhaps it won't be very expensive?

Comment: Nope, removing hintdbs is apparently not a possible operation, nor is calling gallina commands from within the tactics grammar.

Comment: Right, the vernacular commands can't be scripted. Ltac is just for scripting tactics. It might be that you are better off sticking to auto until typeclasses eauto accepts the using clause (that should be the case in the next 8.7 release...)